# google app engine and linking to android project

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, service

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities

Hey guys, i'm following the simple tutorial above. I created my POJO class for my notes. I then right click to add it as an endpoint to the Google app engine. However when I go to do so it says that my project isn't and app engine project.  Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Very simple.. I forgot to generate a Google App Engine back-end! This is done by right clicking your project, select the Google service tool and create the back-end! This might be a missed step for a few people as it is not listed in the tutorial as Google expects you to know some stuff off hand! I Hope this helps someone!